# How to run this program with command line arguments in Ubuntu in C language?

Tags: c, ubuntu, command-line-arguments

I want to be able to use `int main(argc, **argv[])` so that when I type `clr` on the terminal, it will clear the terminal screen.  I just do not know how to use command line arguments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){
    int count;
    char buffer[100];
    char i = 32;
    int p=0;
    char* clr = "clr";
    char* quit = "quit";

    scanf("%s", buffer);
    for(count = 0; count < i; count++){
        buffer[count];
    }
    printf("The first word of your line is: %s\n",buffer);

        if( buffer[p] == *clr){
        system("cls");
        } else if(buffer[p] == *quit){
        exit(0);
        }

       return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `argc, **argv[]` already be in the code?

Comment: It's `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` or equivalently `int main(int argc, char **argv)`. `char **argv[]` would make `argv` a pointer-to-pointer-to-pointer, which is incorrect.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Your code uses `scanf`, so it reads from standard input (typically the keyboard); you'd type the program name, *then* type `clr` or `quit`. If you change it to accept command-line arguments, you'd type the program name followed by any arguments, for example `./foo clr` if your program is called `foo`. That's assuming you fix some of the errors; your string comparisons are all wrong, but you don't seem to be asking about that.

Answer (score -1):

Just get rid of all the useless stuff in your program, and use `strcmp()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char buffer[100];
    char *clr = "clr";
    char *quit = "quit";

    scanf("%s", buffer);
    printf("The first word of your line is: %s\n", buffer);

    if (strcmp(buffer, clr) == 0) {
        system("cls");
    } else if (strcmp(buffer, quit) == 0) {
        exit(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I don't think you're looking for anything to do with command line arguments, based on your question.

If you really want to "type `clr` on the terminal" and have it clear the screen (using this horrible `system()` method), then just do:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    system("cls");
    return 0;
}
```

name your executable file `clr`, and put it in a folder in your path.